how to get renderPass info with pmndrs/postprocessing?
I am used to using renderer.info to get the number of triangles in my scene in three.js. However with pmndrs/postprocessing https://github.com/pmndrs/postprocessing the renderer.info.triangles is always 1. I know this is because the library renders all its effects to a single triangle for performance, but I'm sure there must be a way to get the true number of triangles in your scene out of there somehow, by hooking into the pass chain early enough?

I was able to get this in the end with
const {gl} = useThree();
gl.autoClear = false
gl.info.autoReset = false
useFrame((state) => {
    console.log(gl.info)
            
        state.gl.info.reset()
})  

Not sure if that's intended to be the way you have to do it or not, but it worked for me.
